# Graphical/File output for Grayscale BufferedImage

Tags: java, paint, bufferedimage, repaint, grayscale

I am doing this for a project at school, in which much more functionality will be added later, but I am having trouble getting the basic setup done.

I tried doing this in C++ initially, but decided to switch to Java after reading some documentation on BufferedImage, but I am running into an issue with output.  Essentially this is what I am designing the flow of the program to be:
1) Extract original image's (BMP image that is supplied in grayscale) grayscale values.  2) Create a currentImage variable to preserve the original image and perform the modifications to the image I intend to perform in the later stages of the project.  3) Create a reusable output method that will take the currentImage BufferedImage, and output it to a panel (and maybe a file as well.

Here is what I have so far, which currently results in nothing being outputted to the screen, and when I tried doing System logs, it is not setting the pixel values in my draw mechanism:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImageDriver extends JFrame {
    DrawPanel paintPanel;
    static int width = 1024, height = 768;

    BufferedImage originalImage, currentImage;
    File theImageFile;
    int[][] imageData;

    public ImageDriver() {
        super("Image Processing");
        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        paintPanel = new DrawPanel(width, height);
        add(paintPanel);
    }

    public void updateImageDisplay() {
        System.out.println("In updateImageDisplay!");
        paintPanel.setImage(currentImage);
    }


    public void readImage() {
        try {
            theImageFile = new File("images/img1.bmp");
            originalImage = ImageIO.read(theImageFile);
            currentImage = originalImage;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //get a raster to extract grayscale values
        Raster image_raster = currentImage.getData();

        //get pixel by pixel
        int[] pixel = new int[1];
        int[] buffer = new int[1];

        imageData = new int[image_raster.getWidth()][image_raster.getHeight()];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < image_raster.getWidth() ; i++)
            for(int j = 0 ; j < image_raster.getHeight() ; j++) {
                pixel = image_raster.getPixel(i, j, buffer);
                imageData[i][j] = pixel[0];
                //System.out.println("Pixel at: " + i + " x " + j + ": " + imageData[i][j]);
            }
    }

    public void increaseContrast() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageDriver driver = new ImageDriver();
        driver.setVisible(true);

        driver.readImage();
        driver.updateImageDisplay();

        driver.increaseContrast();
        driver.updateImageDisplay();
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

        public DrawPanel(int width, int height) {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        }

        public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
            System.out.println("In setImage!");
            this.image = image;

            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println("in paintPanel component!");

            g = image.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }

}
```

I have a hunch that it is because I am declaring *image* in my *DrawPanel* to be an empty image at first, and *setImage* is not properly copying over all of its contents upon assignment.  I tried fiddling around with using this:

```
this.image.setData(image.getData());
```

but to no avail.

I missing something here?  Or is a complete re-write if the mechanism in order?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is this (in your `paintComponent` method)...

```
g = image.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
```

Basically, you are painting the image back to itself, instead you should do something like like...

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
```

Using the `Graphics` context you were passed

Comment: *facepalm* thank you!  That worked and outputted it to the window.  Marking as accepted in 6 mins when StackOverflow lets me.  Another quick question too if you have the time, in my case paintComponent is being executed twice, both at the start of the program and whenever I call repaint (2x of my System.out).  Any idea what's causing that?